# Does Gajeel's motion sickness have anything to do with Pantherlily becoming his cat?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the [Chariot event](http://www.fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Chariot), Gajeel becomes motion sick without understanding the reason.

[image]

His case of motion sickness does not develop until the second day of the Grand Magic Games. So does this have anything to do with Pantherlily becoming his "cat"?

Comment: I don't believe we have the answer to this yet. It appears that it will be a plot point later on, as his new-found motion sickness has something to do with his personal growth in the dragonslayer realm.

Comment: Should we close the question until then?

Comment: I don't know how this sort of thing works. Anyone else have a suggestion?

Comment: I sort of feel like they have destroyed it a little, it made it funny that having motion sickness was Natsu's thing...
I actually thought that maybe it was something to do with the Chariot's; like perhaps they had some kind of magic on them.
But seems like they all get it? ..

Comment: Yup, apparently all dragon slayers get motion sickness although I can't recall a moment where Rogue got it though. I can't quite remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the very same chapter when Gajeel still didn't understand why did he get motion sickness, Sting said to Gajeel (in Chapter 276, page 11) that "Well then... You finally got accustomed for it, huh... To being a *real dragon slayer*. Congratulations. Newbie."

We also know that dragon slayer magic can more or less change the user's body itself. So I assume that if a dragon slayer gets strong enough then they will get motion sickness on vehicles. (Not as if it would be important or anything, it's probably just funny.) Wendy doesn't have motion sickness only because she is too weak of a dragon slayer yet. Just as was the case with Gajeel before.

Also, Laxus doesn't have an Exceed partner as far as we know and he has motion sickness too (Chapter 276, page 12).

Comment: Good point on the Laxus part, I haven't noticed that before. =)

Comment: laxus isn't a true dragon slayer. so this is not applicable to him.

Comment: @Sp0T Laxus is dragon slayer enough to get motion sickness, and he doesn't have a "cat", so I think yes, this is quite applicable to him.

Comment: Now that Wendy is strong enough, she do get motion sickness too, although she can negate it with one of her spells, Troia.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really late and stuff, but on the [Fairy Tail Wiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Slayer) it says:

> It seems that, for some reason, all Dragon Slayers of an advanced "level" suffer from severe motion sickness. At lower "levels", this isn't much of a problem, as shown with Gajeel prior to the year X791, having rode on both the Super Mage Giant Phantom MK II and the ship to Tenrou Island with ease. However, after three months of intense training, he, too, became vulnerable to motion sickness, having trouble running on a chain of vehicles during the Chariot event.

So maybe it's because he trained really hard and then it caused him to get to the advanced "level." And that might also be the cause for Wendy not having motion sickness, because she isn't at that level. Although that could also be because she has healing magic, but we still don't know so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

During the chariot event Gajeel says he used to be able to ride on vehicles just fine, Sting replies saying that it just means Gajeel is a real dragon slayer now. I don't know if it has anything to do with getting an Exceed, it seems more like a matter of strength.

Answer (score -1):

This is speculation but many wizards don't need to use transportation for their missions, they can just walk like Laxus.  So the recent episodes say that all Dragon Slayers have motion sickness.

Wendy is probably an exception due to her healing abilities.

Comment: But Gajeel didn't get sick in the "robot" (when he was not Fairy tail) only Natsu did.

Comment: @MichelAyres that was before he got Pantherlily as a partner. the OP is asking if having a Exceed partner has anything to do with it.

Comment: Natsu doesn't think that Happy is transportation so he doesn't have motion sickness.  But while Natsu was on the giant Octopus, he had motion sickness.  You can interpret it that he gets motion sickness because of the state of the mind.  Motion sickness can also be the speed, whereas Natsu is less resistant to motion sickness than other dragon slayers.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that all male dragonslayers get motion sickness.  Female dragonslayers are an exception because they are not as powerful as male dragonslayers to level the playing field.  As well, Wendy has support magic that could possibly prevent her from getting motion sickness.

Comment: I don't think motion sickness of a dragon slayer has anything to do with gender. Wendy is the only female dragon slayer that has been brought out until now, but that is not enough to deduce such a thing, as nothing has been specifically mentioned regarding the same. Though i agree that her "no motion sickness" maybe a result of her support magic that she can cast on herself.

Comment: @debal maybe it is power/age related thou. As Gajeel originally had no problems with transportation.

Comment: @Dimitrimx that can be a possibility.